# Filling an array with inputs from a file in Common Lisp

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

I'm trying to get data from a file to an array char by char in lisp, but I'm very new to common lisp so I got lost on the way. Here's what I've tried so far and got lots of errors:

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)

  (defvar *count* 0)
  (setf my-array (make-array '(10)))
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (do ((char (read-char stream nil)
               (read-char stream nil)))
        ((null char))
      (setf (aref my-array *count*) char)
      (set *count* (+ *count* 1))))
  (print my-array)
)
```

Comment: `set` should be `setq` or `setf`.

Comment: You should use `let` to declare local variables. `defvar` is not normally used inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bad start.  Let's take a look at the errors one by one.

When you do a `defvar`, it defines a global variable (to be more precise, with global lexical scope, dynamic extent).  When you do that inside of a function body, this happens each time the function is run.  This is not what you want.  You want a variable that has only local lexical scope.  Use `let` for that:

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)
  (let ((count 0))                        ; <-
    (setf my-array (make-array '(10)))
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
      (do ((char (read-char stream nil)
                 (read-char stream nil)))
          ((null char))
        (setf (aref my-array count) char)
        (set count (+ count 1))))
    (print my-array)))
```

When you `setf` a variable that doesn't exist, it gets created in the global lexical scope, but some of its behaviour is not specified.  Don't do that.  You want a local variable again.  Use the `let`:

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)
  (let ((count 0)
        (my-array (make-array '(10))))     ; <-
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
      (do ((char (read-char stream nil)
                 (read-char stream nil)))
          ((null char))
        (setf (aref my-array count) char)
        (set count (+ count 1))))
    (print my-array)))
```

`Set` is not `setf`.  I'll leave the specifics aside for now; `set` is almost never what you want.  You could use `setf` there, but there is a convenient shorthand for incrementing a place, `incf`:

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)
  (let ((count 0)
        (my-array (make-array '(10))))
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
      (do ((char (read-char stream nil)
                 (read-char stream nil)))
          ((null char))
        (setf (aref my-array count) char)
        (incf count)))                     ; <-
    (print my-array)))
```

This version at least runs without errors and produces a char vector.  You might replace the loop with a single call to `read-sequence`, and instead of printing, you most likely want to just return the new vector:

```
(defun gppinterpreter (filename)
  (let ((my-array (make-array '(10))))
    (with-open-file (stream filename)
      (read-sequence my-array stream))   ; <-
    my-array))                           ; <-
```

The next steps depend on what structure your file actually has.  You might want to get a string instead of a general vector.  You might want to read *a line* of text, with `read-line`.

Comment: wow thank you so much. not only your answer helped me, it also made me understand the reasoning behind it.